# How to add a bindinglist of checkboxes into a listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, checkbox, bindinglist

I would like to add a BindingList of CheckBoxes into a listBox,here is the code that i have written:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form

{
    BindingList<CheckBox> chBoxBList = new BindingList<CheckBox>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chBox = new CheckBox();
        chBox.Height = 20;
        chBox.Text = "Task" + chBoxBList.Count.ToString();
        chBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        chBox.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        chBoxBList.Add(chBox);
        lBox.DataSource = chBoxBList;//lBox is my ListBox's name


    }
}
```

when I press the add button in my forms the Checkboxes in my Listbox appear as follows:
[image: invcisible CheckBoxes in my ListBox]

If I am to write the above given code for a BindingList of String objects then the behavior of the system is as desired and expected.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: seems like that - http://visualcsharptutorials.com/windows-forms/checkedlistbox-control

Comment: Thank you @Johnny, but the issue with CheckedListBox is that it is not possible to set the fonts of the individual items. I want a solution which provides me this functionality.

Comment: These things are done very well in WPF integrating with WinForm @AdilliAdil

Comment: Thank you @daniele3004, I actually have written an important amount of code in Windows Forms so switching to WPF would take much time..